# Handling two Options in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-option

I have 2 options, and I need to take average of the values they hold.

It is possible that one or both may be missing. If one of the value is missing, I would just take other one as the average. But if both are missing, I would resort to some default value.

How can this be done in a clean way?

I can check absence of value using isEmpty, but then won't that would be same as  null check?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess this is self-explanatory:

```
val option1 = Some(12.0)
val option2 = None
val default = 0.0

val average = (option1, option2) match {
   case (Some(val1), Some(val2)) => (val1 + val2) / 2
   case (None, Some(val2)) => val2
   case (Some(val1), None) => val1
   case (None, None) => default
}
```

... but if not, the basic idea is that you construct a tuple of options, and then pattern match on the tuple.

This has a benefit of explicitly capturing all the four potential cases + having support from the complier - since `Option` is a sealed trait, compiler can check and ensure that all the potential branches of pattern match are covered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if I want to throw an exception instead of default?

Comment: You just throw an exception instead of default :) `case (None, None) => throw new Exception("your exception goes here")`.

Answer (score 4):

You could treat the Options as Seq:

```
val o: Option[Double]
val p: Option[Double]
val default: Double

val s = o.toSeq ++ p.toSeq

val avg = s.reduceOption(_ + _).getOrElse(default) / 1.max(s.size)
```

Comment: Don't need the `.toSeq`.

Comment: @jwvh yeah, I thought about that, but wanted to make it explicit...

Answer (score 1):

```
val v = List(opt1, opt2).flatten

if (v.nonEmpty) {
  v.sum / v.size
} else {
  <default value>
}
```

This can be extended to work with any number of optional values.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
def avg(left: Option[Double], right: Option[Double])(default: => Double): Double =
  left.flatMap(a => right.map(b => (a + b) / 2))
    .orElse(left)
    .orElse(right)
    .getOrElse(default)
```

You `flatMap` over the left option: if it's not empty, you take the right option and `map` its content and average with the content of the left option. If either option is empty, the result is `None`, so you can defined either `left` or `right` as fallback values with `orElse`. Finally, the result is retrieved with `getOrElse` and if both inputs where empty, the `default` is returned.

You can adapt this to adopt any behavior. To make a function that throws if both options are empty you can do the following:

```
val assertAvg = avg(_ : Option[Double], _ : Option[Double])(sys.error("both operands are empty"))
```

This works because the type of `throw` expressions is `Nothing`, which is a subtype of any other type (including `Double`), i.e. it can be returned as a result of any expression, regardless the expected type.

The code (and some tests) are available [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/H18lYaptT366cUZBshd6QQ/10).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should keep average in option and grab default afterwards.

```scala
def avgOpt(of:Option[Double]*) = {
  val s = of.flatten
  s.reduceOption(_ + _).map(_ / s.size)
}

avgOpt(Some(5), None, None).getOrElse(0)    //5
avgOpt(Some(5), Some(3), None).getOrElse(0) //4
avgOpt(None, None).getOrElse(0)             //0
```